# How can I efficiently calculate averages for each row in DataFrame1 based on the n rows in DataFrame2 that are most similar to this DataFrame1 row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 DataFrames (df1, df2), each containing the same columns but different entries. First, for each row in df1 I have calculated a 'similarity score' in df2 based on how similar certain values are to the corresponding column value in the df1 row. I'm then calculating various column averages for the  rows with the highest similarity scores in df2 and storing these averages in lists (a list for each column). After all the averages have been stored, I'm dropping these averages into new columns in df1.

```
    np.random.seed(0)
    cols = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5']

    idx1 = [f'id_{str(n)}' for n in np.random.randint(250, size=3)]
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 6, size=(3, 5)), index=idx1, columns=cols)

    idx2 = [f'id_{str(n)}' for n in np.random.randint(250, size=10)]
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 6, size=(10, 5)), index=idx2, columns=cols)
```

df1

```
            value1  value2  value3  value4  value5
    id_172       1       4       4       4       2
    id_47        4       3       5       1       1
    id_117       5       3       2       1       2
```

df2

```
            value1  value2  value3  value4  value5
    id_165       1       3       4       1       2
    id_25        4       4       4       1       2
    id_77        2       2       1       3       5
    id_72        4       4       3       5       3
    id_9         1       1       5       1       5
    id_148       2       5       2       3       3
    id_115       1       2       2       2       2
    id_208       4       4       3       4       1
    id_243       4       5       2       3       5
    id_197       4       5       5       5       4
```

Below is the code I use to compute the similarity scores. In this example, n=3 denotes calculating avg_val1 and avg_val2 using the 3 rows from df2 with the highest similarity scores.

```
    n = 3
    avg_similarity = []
    avg_val1 = []
    avg_val2 = []
    
    for row in df1.iterrows():
        if isinstance(row, tuple):
            row = row[1]
        
        val1_score = np.where(df2.value1 == row.value1, 0.20, 0)
        val2_score = np.where(df2.value2 == row.value2, 0.20, 0)
        val3_score = np.where(df2.value3 == row.value3, 0.20, 0)
        val4_score = np.where(df2.value4 == row.value4, 0.20, 0)
        val5_score = np.where(df2.value5 == row.value5, 0.20, 0)
    
        df2['similarity_score'] = (
            val1_score + 
            val2_score + 
            val3_score + 
            val4_score + 
            val5_score
        )
    
        comps_df = df2.sort_values(by=['similarity_score'], ascending=False, inplace=False)
        if n and len(comps_df) > n:
            comps_df = comps_df.iloc[:n]
    
        avg_similarity.append(comps_df['similarity_score'].mean(axis=0, skipna=True))
        avg_val1.append(comps_df['value1'].mean(axis=0, skipna=True))
        avg_val2.append(comps_df['value2'].mean(axis=0, skipna=True))
    
    df1.reset_index(drop = False, inplace=True)
    df1['avg_similarity'] = avg_similarity
    df1['avg_val1'] = avg_val1
    df1['avg_val2'] = avg_val2
    df1.set_index(['index'], inplace=True)
```

df1

```
            value1  value2  value3  value4  value5  avg_similarity  avg_val1  avg_val2
    index                                                                             
    id_172       1       4       4       4       2        0.533333       2.0  3.000000
    id_47        4       3       5       1       1        0.400000       2.0  2.666667
    id_117       5       3       2       1       2        0.466667       2.0  3.000000
```

My question is how could I make these series of steps more efficient? I know this is pretty computationally intensive, but I couldn't think of another way to work this out without iterating over df1. One alternative I was considering was making a similarity score matrix where the rows are ids from df1 and the cols are the ids from df2, but I couldn't wrap my brain around how to do that efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

For things like comparing elements between one array to another, numpy is your
friend. However, it will take a heavy mental load if you are not already familar
with numpy and its way of doing things.

Here's the vectorized code using numpy:

```py
n = 3

a = df1.to_numpy()[:, None]
b = df2.to_numpy()
similarity = np.clip(a == b, 0, 0.2).sum(axis=-1)

top_value = np.partition(similarity, -n)[:, -n:]
top_index = np.argpartition(similarity, -n)[:, -n:]

result = df1.copy()
result['avg_similarity'] = top_value.mean(axis=-1)
result['avg_val1'] = b[top_index][:, :, 0].mean(axis=-1)
result['avg_val2'] = b[top_index][:, :, 1].mean(axis=-1)
result['top_matches'] = [', '.join(i) for i in df2.index.to_numpy()[top_index]]
```

Result (`top_matches` added for illustration):

```
        value1  value2  value3  value4  value5  avg_similarity  avg_val1  avg_val2            top_matches
id_172       1       4       4       4       2        0.533333       2.0  3.000000  id_115, id_25, id_165
id_47        4       3       5       1       1        0.400000       4.0  4.333333  id_208, id_25, id_197
id_117       5       3       2       1       2        0.466667       2.0  3.000000  id_115, id_25, id_165
```

The output for row `id_47` doesn't match your example because there are multiple
rows in `df2` with similarly max matching score.

The explanation for these lines will take a lot longer for me to write and I
will update this answer later.